# Making items inside Update() independant of FPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a reaction time game and I've been seeing quite the diversity in results, based on which device I'm using and how many FPS it's running (e.g. PC 60 FPS 0.25 average reaction, Smartphone 30 FPS 0.5 average reaction).

I'm working in a 2D environment as shown:

[image]

The player has a static Y-axis, while the red triangle, the obstacle, is moving along the Y-axis negatively.

I got two classes, one for my player:

```
public ObstacleSpawn oScript;

    public GameObject player;

    public Text warningText;

    public float playerDimensionY;
    float warningFade;
    float warningAlpha;

    public bool isRight = true;
    public bool inAir = false;
    public bool mouseClicked = false;
    public bool mouseClickedTimeCheck;
    public bool thereHaveBeenClicked = false;
    bool warningTextAlive;

    public int flyingSpeed;

    float timeStamp1;
    float timeStamp2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Vector2 sprite_size = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = transform.localScale;
        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;
        float player_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;
        playerDimensionY = player_local_sprite_sizeY;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        warningText.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (warningAlpha);
        mouseClickedTimeCheck = false;

        if (oScript.maxClicks != 10) {

            if (isRight == true && mouseClicked == true) {
                transform.position += Vector3.right * flyingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            } else if (isRight == false && mouseClicked) {
                transform.position += Vector3.left * flyingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

        if (warningTextAlive == true) {
                if (warningFade < 400F) {
                    warningAlpha = 1F;
                    warningFade++;
                } else if (warningFade < 500F) {
                    warningAlpha -= 0.01F;
                    warningFade++;
                } else if (warningFade == 500F) {
                    warningText.text = "";
                    warningAlpha = 1F;
                    warningTextAlive = false;
                    warningFade = 0F;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && oScript.instantiatedObstacle == null) {
                warningText.text = "Slow down - do not click without an obstacle visible" + "\nObstacle spawn-time reset";
                warningTextAlive = true;
                oScript.CancelInvoke ();
                oScript.InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", Random.Range (oScript.randomSpawnMin, oScript.randomSpawnMax), Random.Range (oScript.randomSpawnMin, oScript.randomSpawnMax));
            } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && inAir == false && oScript.instantiatedObstacle != null && thereHaveBeenClicked == false) {
                mouseClicked = true;
                inAir = true;
                mouseClickedTimeCheck = true;
                oScript.canSpawn = true;
                thereHaveBeenClicked = true;

                if (isRight == true) {
                    isRight = false;
                } else if (isRight == false) {
                    isRight = true;
                } 
            } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && inAir == true && oScript.instantiatedObstacle != null) {
                warningText.text = "Slow down - do not click without an obstacle visible" + "\nObstacle spawn-time reset";
                warningTextAlive = true;
                oScript.CancelInvoke ();
                oScript.InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", Random.Range (oScript.randomSpawnMin, oScript.randomSpawnMax), Random.Range (oScript.randomSpawnMin, oScript.randomSpawnMax));
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        inAir = false;
        mouseClicked = false;
    }
}
```

and one for my obstacle:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    //Reaction times: 1.0(4F), 0.9(3.6F), 0.8(3.2F), 0.7(2.8F), 0.6(2.4F), 0.5(2F), 0.4(1.6F), 0.35(1.4F), 0.3(1.2F), 0.25(1F); 

    public PlayerScript pScript;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;
    public GameObject endGamePanel;
    public GameObject infoText;
    public Text Average;
    public Text BestReaction;

    public GameObject instantiatedObstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;
    public float endingSpeed;
    public float speed;
    public float canvasMoveTowardsSpeed;
    public float spawnTime;
    public float maxReactionTime;
    public float reactionTime;

    float obstacleDimensionY;
    float spawnTimeDistance;
    float reactionClick;
    float amountOfTries;
    float panelAlpha = 0F;
    float gamePanelAlpha = 1F;
    private float[] reactionTimeArray = new float[10];

    public int maxClicks;

    public bool canSpawn = true;

    bool reactionCap;
    bool pointOneChange;

    int fade = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawnTimeDistance = 4F;
        maxReactionTime = 1F;

        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax), Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));

        Vector2 sprite_size = obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = obstacle.transform.localScale;
        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;
        float obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;
        obstacleDimensionY = obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
        endGamePanel.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        Average.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        BestReaction.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        infoText.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (gamePanelAlpha);

        if (instantiatedObstacle != null) {
            if (instantiatedObstacle.transform.position.x > 1.78F) {
                instantiatedObstacle.transform.position += new Vector3 (-1, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            } else if (instantiatedObstacle.transform.position.x < -1.78) {
                instantiatedObstacle.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            } else {
                instantiatedObstacle.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }   

            if (instantiatedObstacle.GetComponent<Renderer> ().isVisible != true ) {
                Destroy (instantiatedObstacle);
                pScript.thereHaveBeenClicked = false;
            }
        }

        if (amountOfTries == 10) {
            float moveTowardsSpeed = endingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            player.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (player.transform.position, new Vector2 (0, -2), moveTowardsSpeed);
            if (fade < 100) {
                panelAlpha += 0.01F;    
                gamePanelAlpha -= 0.1F;
                fade++;
            }

        }

        if (maxReactionTime >= 0.4F) {
            pointOneChange = true;
        } else if (maxReactionTime < 0.4F) {
            pointOneChange = false;
        }

        if (maxReactionTime == 1F) {
            reactionCap = true;
        } else {
            reactionCap = false;
        }

        if (pScript.mouseClickedTimeCheck == true && amountOfTries <= 10 && maxClicks != 10) {
            reactionClick = Time.unscaledTime;
            amountOfTries += 1;
            maxClicks += 1;

            reactionTime = reactionClick - spawnTime;

            if (reactionTimeArray [0] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [0] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [1] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [1] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [2] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [2] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [3] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [3] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [4] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [4] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [5] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [5] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [6] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [6] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [7] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [7] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [8] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [8] = reactionTime;
            } else if (reactionTimeArray [9] == 0) {
                reactionTimeArray [9] = reactionTime;
            }

            float averageReaction = (reactionTimeArray[0] + reactionTimeArray [1] + reactionTimeArray [2] + reactionTimeArray [3] + reactionTimeArray [4] + reactionTimeArray [5] + reactionTimeArray [6] + reactionTimeArray [7] + reactionTimeArray [8] + reactionTimeArray [9]) / 10;

            BestReaction.text = "Best reaction: " + Mathf.Min(reactionTimeArray[0], reactionTimeArray[1], reactionTimeArray[2], reactionTimeArray[3], reactionTimeArray[4], reactionTimeArray[5], reactionTimeArray[6], reactionTimeArray[7], reactionTimeArray[8], reactionTimeArray[9]);
            Average.text = "Average reaction: " + averageReaction;

            if (reactionTime <= maxReactionTime && pointOneChange == true) {
                maxReactionTime -= 0.1F;
                spawnTimeDistance -= 0.4F;
            } else if (reactionTime <= maxReactionTime && pointOneChange == false) {
                maxReactionTime -= 0.05F;
                spawnTimeDistance -= 0.2F;
            } else if (reactionTime > maxReactionTime && pointOneChange == true && reactionCap == false) {
                maxReactionTime += 0.1F;
                spawnTimeDistance += 0.4F;
            } else if (reactionTime > maxReactionTime && pointOneChange == false && reactionCap == false) {
                maxReactionTime += 0.05F;
                spawnTimeDistance += 0.2F;
            }
            Debug.Log (string.Format ("ReactionClick: " + reactionClick));
            Debug.Log (string.Format ("ReactionTime: " + reactionTime));
            Debug.Log (string.Format ("Max Reaction Time: " + maxReactionTime));
        }
    }

    public void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            spawnTime = Time.unscaledTime;
            instantiatedObstacle = (GameObject)Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(0.50F , (spawnTimeDistance + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY), -1), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log (string.Format ("Spawn time: " + spawnTime));

        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            spawnTime = Time.unscaledTime;
            instantiatedObstacle = (GameObject)Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.50F , (spawnTimeDistance + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY), -1), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log (string.Format ("Spawn time: " + spawnTime));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in my obstacle class, I'm getting the users reaction time with following line:

```
reactionTime = reactionClick - spawnTime;
```

spawnTime being Time.time from when the obstacle appears
and
reactionClick being the Time.time when the player clicks.

However, as this line is getting called in my Update() function, it is very dependent on FPS, which causes my issue stating previously.

How do I make the results independent from device FPS, so they're stable across different devices?

I've considered and tried unscaledTime and multithreading, but without luck.

Comment: You don't seem to be taking into account the time between each tick of the Update() method in your calculations. You need to do that to ensure smooth animation/handling.

Comment: @ManoDestra could you give an example on how to do this

Comment: Been a while since I've done it, but I think it's regarding Time.deltaTime from memory. Look that up via the Unity documentation. They've got tons on how to use it.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the difference in frame time between 30 and 60fps? thats a difference of less than 0.02s. Sadly your code is not exactly nice to read, but i wonder, you seem to spawn multiple obstacles, but only keep track of a single point in time ...

Comment: @yes That was my assumption. The code is netted together, so only 1 obstacle is present at a time

Comment: i think you should untie the gordic knot a bit and better seperate your logic. maybe it gets instanly evident. if you look back at this in a year it will take you hours to figure out what everything does. extract some connected code into functions, the falling obstacles could fall completely on their own and so on.

Comment: or maybe i misunderstood you completely. i just looked at your profile and saw you already asked the same question yet slightly different. i think this is how close youll get in unity. youll only get the time at the beginning of a frame and the time the last frame took. but for a game that should be totally sufficient, no human beeing can tell the difference whether its 2 or 2.02 seconds (unless its continous motion, but its about reaction time). just display 2 seconds, the user wont notice the difference.

Comment: @yes The difference is much greater than .02. If I play the game on my PC I have approx. .25-.3 reaction time. If I do it on my phone however, I receive a result between .45-.5.

Comment: well i dont see a major logical flaw in just calculating the delta time between the frame you spawned the piece and the frame you click/touch. the difference whether you do that at 30 or 60fps should be marginal at best. so IMO the problem lies elsewhere, i might be wrong. but having easliy readable code never hurts, so as said before, refactor a bit maybe it gets evident instantly

Comment: @yes All-right, I'm working on cleaning up my code - So you simply just suggest to expand my Update content into several functions, or should I also take advantage of more classes? EDIT: I know this is not directly related to the question, but now I got you I hope you'll understand :-)

Comment: make sure each thing really only cares for what its supposed to do. currently your player invokes spawning, but not at start, then its done by the spawner which mainly handles the click timing (but also obstacle movement), which is reliant on input which is handled by the player though. so let the player care about input and timing (just because its so tightly connected, but it could well be seperated), the spawner about spawning and the obstacle about its movement.

Comment: @WONDERGG Did you ever solve your issue? Were any of the provided answers correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using the FixedUpdate function instead of / in addition to the Update function should solve this issue.

> This (FixedUpdate) function is called every fixed framerate frame, if the MonoBehaviour is enabled. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

This will mean that you can more accurately calculate your time irrespective of rendered framerate.

Additional information and explanation of the FixedUpdate can be found here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10993/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-fixedupdat.html

Answer (score 0):

Beside @Zze answer i would like to share with you [**Time.deltaTime**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). What it state that:

> The time in seconds it took to complete the last frame (Read Only).
>
> Use this function to make your game frame rate independent.

Same kind of example of your current scenario is:

> If you add or subtract to a value every frame chances are you should
> multiply with Time.deltaTime. When you multiply with Time.deltaTime
> you essentially express: I want to move this object 10 meters per
> second instead of 10 meters per frame.
>
> When called from inside MonoBehaviour's FixedUpdate, returns the fixed
> framerate delta time.

so if you want make something independent of frame you should need to use Time.deltaTime and use it with your multiplication.